# SerializedObject is not defined in a referenced assembly c#

Tags: c#, ios, json, iphone, xamarin

I seem to be having difficulty writing my object list to NSUserDefaults using a SerializedObject method that only returns the error *"The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard'"*. I don't understand what this means and how to fix it.

The list I want to serialize:

```
    public class doubleVariableDateAndName
    {
        public string Name;
        public DateTime DueDay;
    }
    public List<doubleVariableDateAndName> reminderList = new List<doubleVariableDateAndName>();
```

How I am serializing it:

```
    public void SaveList(List<doubleVariableDateAndName> reminderList)
    {
        var serializedContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(reminderList);
        NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetString(serializedContent, "remindersStored");
    }
```

And how I am deserializing it:

```
    public List<doubleVariableDateAndName> GetReminderList()
    {
        var userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults;
        var serializedContent = userDefaults.StringForKey("remindersStored");
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(serializedContent))
        {
            var reminderList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<doubleVariableDateAndName>>(serializedContent);
            return reminderList;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried adding that reference to see if that works? Forgive me if this is a dumb question - do you know how to add a reference to a project? Usually this exception means "I'm trying to create an object of type x and to create it I need a whole bag of dll's but I'm missing one so my attempt to create the object to deserialize into is failing."

Comment: No sorry, I don't know how to add a reference, I am relatively new to this. Would you be able to tell me how?

Comment: Sure :-) You normally find with this sort of question if you google it you'll find lots of material out there already. For example there's a video at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5QXav2r1piE For the assembly you need you'll probably need to try Assemblies \ Framework in the top left corner. If you give it a go but are still stuck give me another shout.